# How to use dynamic sql to insert into select from "dynamic table"?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle12c

I want to dynamically pass the table name to my insert into select statement. However, I am getting missing keyword error when executing below block.

```
declare
v_tbl varchar2(4000):='TBL';
begin
execute immediate 'Insert into emp(col1, col2, col3)
                   select fname, lname, origin 
                   from source src
                   inner join v_tbl on src.id=tab.id';
end;
```

I am doing this dynamically because there will be more than one table I will loop through the dynamic sql. There are multiple rows from the select statement so I can't pass the values to a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare
v_tbl varchar2(4000):='TBL';
begin
execute immediate 'Insert into emp(col1, col2, col3)
                   select fname, lname, origin 
                   from source src
                   inner join ' || v_tbl ||' on src.id=tab.id';
end;
```

Comment: Shouldn't that last line read `' tab on src.id=tab.id'`?

Comment: I am getting ORA-00905 missing keyword.

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the space inside the quote. '||v_tbl||'